# Base64 excel file stream Aspose.Cells.CellsException

Tags: excel, base64, aspose-cells

I have a Base64 string of xls file. When I try to open base64 stream 
it throws the following exception

***Aspose.Cells.CellsException*** : This file's format is not supported or you don't specify a correct format.

```
public Stream ConvertFileToStream(string fileBase64)
{
        var fileAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileBase64);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileAsBytes);
        return stream;
  }


public void Open(Stream fileSource)
{
        FileFormatUtil.DetectFileFormat(fileSource);
        _workbook = new Workbook(fileSource);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the related part of the code and it worked. Now I'm able to work with base64 excel strings.

First, I used **BinaryWriter** to convert file to stream.

```
public Stream ConvertFileToStream(string fileBase64, NameValueCollection formData, string fileName)
{
        var fileAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileBase64);
        var  stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(fileAsBytes);

        return stream;
}
```

Then I changed my Open method to convert file to Workbook.

```
public void Open(Stream fileSource)
{
        fileSource.Position = 0;
        FileFormatUtil.DetectFileFormat(fileSource);
        _workbook = new Workbook(fileSource);
}
```